# Use the $ symbol as text, not as a variable in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dollar ($) sign in password string treated as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557834/dollar-sign-in-password-string-treated-as-variable)

I am using a code where there has to be a $ in the text.

```
$curlObj = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, "URL");
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:$ape0ZDPvxE/");
curl_exec($curlObj);
curl_close($curlObj);
```

As you can see, the password is md5'ed, and thus there is a $ in it. When I execute this, I get an undefined variable exception. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: FYI: `md5` doesn't have the `$` character, that's another encoding scheme.

Comment: :S What is RTFM? "Read The Freaking Manual?"

Comment: I know md5 doesn't have it, I said it to trick the script kiddies :P

Comment: dont be so high on this guy, he looks like a noob :)

Comment: Thank you Shaheer, your the first guy who acted nice to me here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been a while since I wrote PHP, but I believe that if you use single quotes(') instead of double quotes("), PHP won't evaluate it.

You may also be able to escape it with a backslash: `\$`.

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes

```
'user:$ape0ZDPvxE/'
```

Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 3):

Switch string quoting styles, `'user:$ape0ZDPvxE'` - single quotes do not interpolate variables. Or escape it: `"user:\$ape0ZDPvxE"`. The backslash tells PHP to treat the $ as a literal $ sign and not as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes, or escape it:

```
echo '$';
echo "\$";
```