# Dollar sign in text when passing variable

Tags: php4

I got stricky/old php code, I just try to clean it  , fix some bugs, and so on. Also the server uses php 4 too.

The problem is the following:

I get some data back from the database, I work with those data and show them. If the result contains a dollar sign, the PHP  try to handle it as a variable.

For example :

```
$result  = $this->sqlresult('SELECT * From Tablename  where id=15');
$details = $result['description'];
echo $details;
```

Let me show an example what's happening , when the $result['description'] contains any wrong text, like 'This book is available for $148':
It usually doesn't show anything or show a  wrong text , like This book is available for 48.

I have tried a  preg replace functions on the details, I was looking for char changes , or html_special_chars ,  and tried those too, but nothing happened or not the original text came up.

```
preg_replace('/\$ /','/&#36/;' $details);
```

I know , that the double quotes on passing variables causes a  similar error. I checked [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557834/dollar-sign-in-password-string-treated-as-variable/2557853#comment12358535_2557853)  too, but it wasn't a  solution for me.

Current solution is just adding an extra space between the price amount the $ sign, but I am looking for  a better one.

```
preg_replace('/\$/','/\$ /' $details);
```

Comment: Your example looks ok to me. Can you explain exactly how it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, could you please show some more code? For example, what do you do with $details?

Comment: The problem is occured,  if the  $result['description'] contains any text with $ sign , like "this travel costs $148."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use escape characters? This book is \$148.

Comment: preg_replace , what I've tried, exactly try to do this. Didn't work.

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem though to what I know. Maybe you try it this way though i'm sure it won't work but who knows until you try it right? echo '"' . $details . '"';

Comment: Did you mean this one?preg_replace("/\\\$/", "\\$", $details); Yes, I have tried.