# Dollar ($) sign in form input string treated as variable in php

Tags: php

> ```
> $name =$form['values']['name'];    // for example if user input "$dkyafgh01" then    // $name = "$dkyafgh01"
>    echo  $name;
> ?>
> ```

Question:     for example if user input `"$dkyafgh01"` the data come in `$name = "$dkyafgh01"` in the variable $name `"$dkyafgh01"` treated as variable while as it is string. How to tell php that it treated as string. i searched on stackoverflow and get following help 
  [1]: [Dollar ($) sign in password string treated as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557834/dollar-sign-in-password-string-treated-as-variable) but not help in my case. because data come from input field.$name returns empty.

Comment: I don't understand, are you using Drupal 7 or Codeigniter?

Comment: drupal,yii and CI integrated at the same time? i'm confused use single qoutes BTW

Answer (score 5):

Use single quote

```
$name = '$dkyafgh01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$_POST`, or `$_GET`, use `$_REQUEST`

```
# price is '$5'
echo ($_POST['price']); # prints '5'
echo ($_REQUEST['price']); # prints '$5'
```