# Insertion of $ into textarea using Selenium & PHP

Tags: php, json, selenium

I have a text area that I have to insert a small snippet of *PHP* code into, of the format

```
$value = someFunction("Parameter") . ' and concatenated string.';
```

However, selenium uses the dollar sign to reference variables, as `${variable_name}` and so it escapes them from text. I tried just inserting the above string, but it always inserts without the dollar sign.

I also tried storing it in a variable, in hopes that using their referencing style would allow me to insert unescaped dollar signs in to the string, but no luck. You also aren't able to escape the `$` as it is not a valid *JSON* escape character.

Note, this is not a duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557834/dollar-sign-in-password-string-treated-as-variable) What they are describing is variable injection into strings in *PHP*. What I am describing uses Selenium Builder in Firefox to automate actions on a web page. When I use the `setElementText` function in Selenium, it will insert text into a textarea. There just happens to be a `$` in my text, however, and this is a reserved character for Selenium to identify variables (using the above syntax), so when setElementText is executed, the `$` is stripped from the text (note: BEFORE the form has been submitted, this is not *PHP* rendering the text incorrectly, it never has the `$` inserted at any point beyond the *JSON* file it is read from).

UPDATE

Here are some additional details.

This is the *JSON* command that stores a variable in selenium. The "text" being stored is the string I want to insert into the textarea

```
{
  "type": "store",
  "text": "$value = 'Number of People: ' . count(\"Person\");",
  "variable": "php_derived_value"
}
```

And to access that, we can do something like this:

```
{
  "type": "setElementText",
  "locator": {
    "type": "css selector",
    "value": "div > textarea"
  },
  "text": "${php_derived_value}"
}
```

Notice that this dollar sign is used as an escape character to reference the variable. The problem lies with the fact that the text I am inserting will then skip the dollar sign.

[image: Here is an image of the textarea after the selenium command has executed, but before the form has been submitted. Notice that it has skipped the dollar sign, but the rest of the string is in tact.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dollar ($) sign in password string treated as variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557834/dollar-sign-in-password-string-treated-as-variable)

Comment: I do not believe these are the same problems. What you've linked references PHP variable injection into strings, however my issue is purely a problem with Selenium inserting raw text into a text area. Before submission of the form, I can see that Selenium has escaped the $ character.

Comment: @JeffC sorry, meant to tag you in the previous comment.

Comment: Please post the code you are using and describe the error/failure.

Comment: @JeffC I have added details and code. Please let me know what you think.