# $ sign is in database name, so it’s recognise as a variable in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This $ sign is in the database name so it’s identified as a variable in PHP. So can i know, how can i using this query in php ?

The problem is $ sign is in database name.

**DATA$SALES**

```
<?php
$sql = "select service id from DATA$SALES.SERVICE_DATA where service_name in('202200*)";
$result = oci_parse($c,$sql);
oci_execute ($result); 
?>
```

Comment: Escape it `\$` or use single quotes so it is not escaped. See [strings in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: use single quotes instead of double quotes. PHP parse ' $sql' as string $sql with single quotes. but will parse "$sql" as variable with double quotes

Comment: Are you using the term "database" incorrectly? That looks like a schema reference. The question you are asking is the same, but if you work with data in an Oracle database, it would help to learn at least the basics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dollar ($) sign in password string treated as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557834/dollar-sign-in-password-string-treated-as-variable)

Comment: Use a PHP 'NOWDOC', see [PHP 5.3 "NOWDOCS" make SQL escaping easier](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/php-53-quotnowdocsquot-make-sql-escaping-easier).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NOWDOC](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/php-53-quotnowdocsquot-make-sql-escaping-easier) syntax:

```
<?php

$sql = <<<'END'
select service id from DATA$SALES.SERVICE_DATA where service_name in('202200')
END;

$result = oci_parse($c,$sql);
oci_execute ($result); 

?>
```